# Expand regex on multiple lines in Vim

Tags: vim, regular-expression

I am working on removing comments from a C source file. Let's focus on multiline comments 
**/* ... */** and ignore the inline ones (//)

The following command seems to work with (solaris) sed:

```
s:/\*.*\*/::g
```

However in Vim (7.2) it only works if the whole comment is on one line. How can I make it so the `.*` spreads over multiple lines? I tried doing the follwing

```
s:/\*.*[\r]*.*\*/::g
```

but it didn't work ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you'd want

```
s:/\*\_.*\*/::g
```

`\_` tells it to include newlines in the following character set (well, `.`, anyway).